# Intersect two arrays with tolerance

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 2 arrays of data, from which I want to extract common elements. Matlab's `intersect` does this job. But it returns elements that are exactly the same. What if I want to extract elements with some tolerance? Say for e.g

```
A = [1 2 3.0002 4.125 5.89]; 
B = [2 3.012 4.126]
```

I want to extract elements that are same up to 2 decimal places. So I want the answer to be `[2 4.12]` . Is there any built-in function to do this? Or How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just `round` the input:

```
C = intersect(round(A,2),round(B,2))
```

`floor` and `ceil` are also options, depending on what you really want to achieve.

Comment: For matlab versions earlier than 2014b, use `C = intersect(round(A*10^n)/10^n,round(B*10^n)/10^n)` where `n` is the number of decimal places you want your elements to be same.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it manually as follows. This picks the output values from `A`; if you want to pick from `B` just swap `A` and `B` in the code:

```
A = [1 2 3.0002 4.125 5.89]; 
B = [2 3.012 4.126];
tol = .01;
result = A(any(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:).', B(:))) < tol, 1));
```